# "Reticent" or "Reluctant"?

Tags: word-choice

Consider ([Source](https://books.google.com/books?id=QtJoCwAAQBAJ&pg=RA13-PR95&dq=1100%20words%20you%20need%20to%20know%20week35%20day%201&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwivkKH_sb3NAhXrNpoKHXHBAkUQ6AEIHjAA#v=onepage&q=1100%20words%20you%20need%20to%20know%20week35%20day%201&f=false), *See: **Sample Sentences***):

> He was never **reticent** to lampoon the egotist in order to bring him down with alacrity.

Some time ago, I heard from [Charles Harrington Elster](http://members.authorsguild.net/chelster/) that we should avoid using ***reticent*** when we want to imply ***reluctant***.

I know that **to lampoon** means some kind of ***reprimand, rebuke or, in general, criticize***. 
As far as I know, criticism is an act that usually is done with speaks and talks. On the other hand, since when you criticize someone or something you do do something. Shouldn't it be:

> He was never **reluctant** to lampoon the egotist in order to bring him down with alacrity.

---

**Note**: Currently, I am concentrated completely on the **formal** English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The distinction is subtle, and according to [Garner's](https://www.vocabulary.com/articles/chooseyourwords/reluctant-reticent/), the use of reticent to mean reluctant is 'a nearly universal form that only "language 
stalwards" [...] object to". In this case, since "lampoon" has a sense of something spoken the use of 'reticent' is quite defendable.

I'd prefer 'reticent about lampooning' myself, [ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=reticent%20to%2C%20reticent%20about&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Creticent%20to%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Creticent%20about%3B%2Cc0) suggest that this is still the more common form.

Answer (score 0):

> reticent

is what goes through your thinking process

> reluctant

is the lack of action (for whatever reason).

> He was reticent and therefore reluctant to speak out.
>   *He thought is was not necessary to speak out and therefore did not speak out*